# How to close plots in function in python?

Tags: python, matplotlib

In my code I want to plot and close the figure in function, I expect I could see figures pop-up and close for 10 times, but I am very surprised to see sometimes it just pops up blank figure, also use `plt.pause(0.001)` or `plt.pause(0.0001)` makes different display results!

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import time
sampling_points = 30
figure_list=[]
def plot_cycle_data(a1,a2):
    #for each cycle, plot all 
    global figure_list
    x = range(sampling_points)

    #close if opened before
    if len(figure_list) != 0:
       plt.close(figure_list[0])
       figure_list[:] = []

     fig_cycle, ax = plt.subplots(4, 2)
     ax[0, 0].scatter(x,a1[0])
     ax[1, 0].scatter(x,a1[1])
     ax[2, 0].scatter(x,a1[2])
     ax[3, 0].scatter(x,a1[3])
     ax[0, 1].scatter(x,a2[0])
     ax[1, 1].scatter(x,a2[1])
     ax[2, 1].scatter(x,a2[2])
     ax[3, 1].scatter(x,a2[3])
     #plt.draw()
     plt.pause(0.0001)
     plt.show(block=False)
     figure_list.append(fig_cycle)

# for each chamber, 4 optical channels,30(or n) data points per channel 
container_1 = np.zeros([4,sampling_points]) 
container_2 = np.zeros([4,sampling_points]) 

for i in range(10):
    plot_cycle_data(container_1,container_2)
    time.sleep(0.5)
```

Answer (score 1):

it turns out plot 8 subplots need a long time to refresh, at lease 0.3 seconds here, so just change `plt.pause(0.001)` to `plt.pause(0.3)` will figure out this problem